# A proof that an algebraic variety is path-connected

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I am working on a proof that an algebraic variety on reals $M \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, $n>2$ is path connected.

The sketch of the proof is the following:

1) I define a map $F:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $F(M)$ is a convex set.

2) I prove that the jacobian of $F$ is a singular matrix only for isolated points. Hence, given two points $x_1,x_2 \in M$ there exist $F(x_1), F(x_2) \in F(M)$ and a path $\gamma$ that connects $F(x_1)$ and $F(x_2)$ such that $\gamma$ does not pass in any critical value. Thus the path $F^{-1}(\gamma)$ is connected in $M$ and connects $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Is correct this proof?

And Is it possible to use the information of the critical points of $F$ in $M$ to  find the homology groups for $M$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The trouble is that you do not know if $F$ is a covering map over $F(M)$ outside of the set of critical points. For instance, you can have a local diffeomorphism $R^2\to R^2$ which is not a diffeomorphism and have $M$ (a two point set) contained in the preimage of a point. There are books on computing connected components of algebraic sets, like "Algorithms in Real Algebraic Geometry".

Comment: The argument is that for every point $y \in \gamma \subset F(M)$  there is a convex neighborhood $N(y)$ and $F^{-1}(N(y))$ is homeomorphic to $N(y)$.

Comment: Hence, it is not possible to find two disconnected open set $U_1, U_2 \subset M$ such that they separate two points of $F^{-1}(\gamma)$, because every two points of $F^{-1}(\gamma)$ it exists an open set homeomorphic to a convex open set.

Comment: Alverado: This is not an argument. Think of the examples which I mentioned.

Comment: Thanks, for ypur comment. Now I realize that F is a covering map, because  $F(M)$ has a non empty interior and its dimension is higher than 1, then F(M) minus some critical points is locally convex. Since, for every $y \in F(M)$ it exists a neighborhood $N(y)$ such that F maps homeomorphically to $F^{-1}(N(y))$. Now, consider $B(y,\epsilon) \subset N(y) $ a open ball inside. Hence $F(M) \cap B(y,\epsilon) \subset N(y) $ is open and convex (path-connected) and $F$  maps homeomorphic to $F^{-1}(F(M) \cap B(y,\epsilon) \subset N(y) )$. Therefore $F$ is a covering map.

Comment: You are still wrong, you are confusing local homeomorphisms and covering maps. An example to think about is one of a **surjective**  local diffeomorphism $R^2\to R^2$ which is not 1-1 (a covering map would have to be 1-1). See e.g. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/147110/surjective-entire-functions-without-critical-points

Comment: I see that my argument works, if $F$ is injective.

Comment: Yes, but if $F$ is injective then it is a homeomorphism to its image (by invariance of domain theorem), so you do not need any arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Think of the following examples:

1. $F(z)=z^2$, $z\in {\mathbb C}$, $M=\{-1, 1\}$.
2. $F(z)=\exp(z)$, $z\in {\mathbb C}$, $M=\{0, 2\pi i\}$.